# Prove that if $A$ is a symmetric orthogonal matrix, then $1$ and $-1$ are the only eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra

Since $A$ is symmetric , it is orthogonally diagonalizable $\implies $ $A$ is similar to some diagonal matrix $D$. $\implies$ $\det(A) = \det(D)$

Since $A$ is orthogonal $\implies \det(A) = \pm1 \implies \det(D) = \pm1$

I know that $A$ and $D$ have the same eigenvalues and the same trace.

I am not sure what the next step is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ is diagonalizable with $\det(A)=det(D)=\pm1$ and $D$ orthogonal what can you say about the elements of $D$ on the diagonal?

Comment: I didn't realise we could imply that D was orthogonal! The theorem in my book did not say it was orthogonal anyway. Well, in that case the diagonal elements must be 1 or -1 or D is not orthogonal.

Comment: I see, the product of two orthogonal matrices are orthogonal $\implies$ $P^T(AP) $ is orthogonal $\implies  D$ orthogonal.

Comment: I think you have it by yourselt. So I will make my answer a comment. It is more appropriate as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ is symmetric orthogonal matrix
so we can use one of the following :
$A^{T}=A$ and $A^{T}=A^{-1}$ or $A^{T}A=AA^{T}=I$.

Now let $k$ be an eigenvalue of $A$. Then
$Ax=kx$ with $x$ is different from zero.

$x = Ix = (A^{-1}A)x = A^{-1}(Ax)=A^{-1}(kx) =k(A^{-1}x) = k(Ax) = k^{2}x$

Then $x=k^{2}x \implies (k^2 -1)x=0 \implies k^2 -1=0 \implies k= \pm 1$.
proved :)